# HTML div positioning off

Tags: positioning, html

I am positioning points on a map through divs.

I have the following code:

```
<div id="map" style = "background-image:url('map.gif');width:382px;height:524px;">

<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:222px; left:204px;">
<a href=""><img src="bullet.gif" border=0>Point</a>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

When I add this code on my page, the point is not on the map so I added a position:relative

```
<div id="map" style = "background-image:url('map.gif');width:382px;height:524px;position:relative;">
```

Now the point is on the map but its a bit off from where I initially wanted. Does anyways have a fix for this? Also The points are in different positions in different browsers. Is there a way to standardize where the position is?

Comment: Any padding/margin/borders being applied? those will affect positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend only using one level (instead of cascading), also, spans for the overlay.

```
<div>
  <div>
  </div>
<div>
```

use

```
<div style=...>     the map
</div>
<span style=...></span>   an overlayed rectangle
<span style=...></span>   an overlayed rectangle
```

is this ok for you? If not pleas specify and i will adapt it.

Comment: Is this the way to standardize the positioning throughout the different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

well you may need to adjust the "top" and "left" values, since the "point" is now positioned absolutely relative to the "map" div. 
Check this out if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/DK9wT/6/

Comment: Thats also the problem though. I have many points but I don't want to manually adjust each one.

Comment: Well, this could be fixed easily, but it depends on how you are getting the values for each marker. I've updated the example here http://jsfiddle.net/DK9wT/7/ . For the example's sake, I assumed the data is found in some dynamically generated JSON named points. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I am just manually placing them on the page through divs. I thought that since all the points are shifted over a bit I could just shift them back through a wrapper div but then everything messes up when I try.